# how to remove line break in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using the `xsl:copy-of` to display the complete node but it adds additional lines to the top and bottom.

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<root>
  <E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <ApplicationData>
      <TraceData>
        <DataItem>
          <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
            <TraceIdentifier>MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
          </TraceRecord>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>This should not be a table</td>
              <td>It must be a text</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </DataItem>
      </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
  </E2ETraceEvent>
</root>
```

## XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:te="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"
                exclude-result-prefixes="te">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <body>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <xsl:for-each select="//te:E2ETraceEvent">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <xsl:for-each select=".//te:TraceData//te:DataItem">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <xmp>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="./node()" />
                          </xmp>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Output

*between quotes there is a space and empty lines above and below the actual node*

```
"
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
            <TraceIdentifier>MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
        </TraceRecord>
    "
```

## Desired Output

*between quotes there is a space but no line, inside of the node*

```
"       <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
            <TraceIdentifier>MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
        </TraceRecord>"
```

Comment: I am seeing the out put like "                                                                           <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
        <TraceIdentifier>MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
    </TraceRecord>

Comment: extra line before the <traceRecord

Comment: Please post enough code to enable us to reproduce the problem. There are no quotes being output by your XSLT, so that alone already doesn't make sense.

Comment: In particular, show us any xsl:output and xsl:strip-space declarations in the stylesheet. Also tell us whether you are using MSXML, which handles whitespace differently from every other processor.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i did added new modification to my question. I did provided more information. Please advise.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot reproduce your output using your code. What's more, i don't really understand what you're doing here: why are you adding `<xmp>` to an HTML table? And why are you copying a a block of nodes - in another namespace(!) - into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the part `./node()` to `*` should solve the issue

Also you may probably ask how to remove the namespace that adds into the table tag

Based on [Remove namespace declaration from XSLT stylesheet with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465002/remove-namespace-declaration-from-xslt-stylesheet-with-xslt) add following parts

```
<!-- Copy elements -->
<xsl:template match="*" priority="-1">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Copy all other nodes -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" priority="-2">
   <xsl:copy />      
</xsl:template>
```

and change

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much cilerler for you answer it works perfect.