# How to get HTML text in XML via XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

It looks like `exclude-result-prefixes` does not apply to `xsl:copy-of`.
When I run following XML, its output has namespace on `<table>` tag which is not the desired behavior in my case.  The ultimate goal is getting DataItem element which may contain XML/HTML type of text and should not be modified for any reason.  So what is the best approach to get DataItem **as it is**?

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<root>
  <E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <ApplicationData>
      <TraceData>
        <DataItem>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>This should not be a table</td>
              <td>It must be a text</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </DataItem>
      </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
  </E2ETraceEvent>
</root>
```

## XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:te="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"
                exclude-result-prefixes="te">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <body>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <xsl:for-each select="//te:E2ETraceEvent">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <xsl:for-each select=".//te:TraceData//te:DataItem">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <xmp>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
                          </xmp>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Output

```
<table xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
        <tr>
          <td>This should not be a table</td>
          <td>It must be a text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

## Desired Output

```
<table>
        <tr>
          <td>This should not be a table</td>
          <td>It must be a text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what is the best approach to get DataItem as it is?

The best way to get the source node ***as it is*** is to copy it. However, 
*copy* means *copy* - including the namespace/s.

If you don't want the namespace (i.e. you **don't** want to  get the source node ***as it is***), then you cannot copy the existing nodes. You must construct new ones instead. So rather than doing:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
```

do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
```

and then:

```
<xsl:template match="*"> 
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this variant does not copy attributes.

Comment: Thank you for prompt and detailed reply.  When I say _as it is_ I meant source file  (XML) not the XSL processed one.  Based on what you said, it is not possible to get everything as it is without the namespace.  Well, if the next best thing is construct a new one then it is fine, but I'm looking for a solution to get exactly what XML provides between tags, even a space should stay as space and not stripped off and/or added into the result.  Do you think anything that may cause an issue on that matter? (beside missing attributes)  Thank you!

Comment: I am afraid you may be misunderstanding something very basic here: in your source XML, the `<table>` element and all its descendants are in the `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"` namespace. So "as it is in the source" would necessarily include the namespace.

Comment: Upps, I'm sorry you are right, it was my bad.  Actually I just replied someone elses question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349678/how-to-remove-line-break-in-xslt but realized that my response will also create a new problem that, I mentioned here, and became curious.  Since I don't deal with XSL often, I would like to complete the journey.  Therefore I would like to know your thoughts about _Do you think anything that may cause an issue on that matter? (beside missing attributes)_  Thank you again.

Comment: Found my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465002/remove-namespace-declaration-from-xslt-stylesheet-with-xslt Thank you again!